# How do I match multiple bytes at arbitrary positions?

Tags: rust

I have to match bytes in a `&[u8]` and want to simplify my code.
Right now it looks like this:

```
fn f(s: &[u8]) {
    if Some(&b'A') == s.get(5) && Some(&b'X') == s.get(16) &&
        (Some(&b'B') == s.get(17) || Some(&b'C') == s.get(18)) {
    } else if Some(&b'1') == s.get(4) && Some(&b'2') == s.get(7) && Some(&b'D') == s.get(10) {
    }
}
```

I know about [nom](https://github.com/Geal/nom), but it does not make this particular case simpler, although I'm using [nom](https://github.com/Geal/nom) afterwards to extract the data after the match.

So my first attempt to simplify code is to write these macros:

```
macro_rules! m {
    ($ch:expr, $pos:expr) => {{
        Some(&$ch) == line.get($pos)
    }};
    ($ch1:expr, $ch2:expr, $pos:expr) => {{
        Some(&$ch1) == line.get($pos) || Some(&$ch2) == line.get($pos)
    }}
}
```

It reduces code size, and decreases the possibility of making a mistake,
but I want more:

```
macro_rules! match_several {
    ($($ch:expr, $pos:expr),*, $last_ch:expr, $last_pos:expr) => {{
        (Some(&$ch) == line.get($pos) &&)* Some(&$last_ch) == line.get($last_pos)
    }}
}
```

But the compiler gives this error:

```
 error: local ambiguity: multiple parsing options: built-in NTs expr ('last_ch') or expr ('ch').
  --> lib.rs:45:32
   |
45 |     if match_several!(b'P', 4, b' ', 5, b'A', 12) {
   |        ------------------------^^^^-------------- in this macro invocation
```

Test code:

```
let line: &'static [u8] = b"0123P 6789ABA";
println!("match result {:?}", match_several!(b'P', 4, b' ', 5, b'A', 12));
```

Comment: Can you include the code that you used to test `match_several!`?

Comment: @E_net4 Done, I include "Test code"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the macro to:

```
macro_rules! match_several {
    ($($ch:expr, $pos:expr),*) => {{
        $(Some(&$ch) == line.get($pos))&&*
    }}
}
```

Note that I'm using `&&` as the separator, and I got rid of `$last_ch` and `$last_pos`.  This works because you can use *any* token other than `+` or `*` as a separator, and `&&` is a single token.

Comment: *you can use any token other than + or * as a separator*. WHAT. Mind blown.

Answer (score 3):

Repetitive patterns in this case could be abstracted as somewhat useful functions.

```
#[inline]
fn all_match(s: &[u8], pattern: &[(u8, usize)]) -> bool {
    pattern.into_iter().all(|&(b, p)| s.get(p) == Some(&b))
}

#[inline]
fn any_match(s: &[u8], pattern: &[(u8, usize)]) -> bool {
    pattern.into_iter().any(|&(b, p)| s.get(p) == Some(&b))
}

fn f(s: &[u8]) {
    let and_pattern = [(b'A', 5), (b'X', 16)];
    let or_pattern = [(b'B', 17), (b'C', 18)];
    if all_match(s, &and_pattern) 
       && any_match(s, &or_pattern) {
    } else if all_match(s, &[(b'1', 4), (b'2', 7), (b'D', 10)]) {
    }
}
```